# How to create a ring in MAGMA with relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, magma-cas

I'm using MAGMA221 and would like to create a ring over $GF(2)$ with respect to a list of relations. Here's what I have so far:

$\mathtt{Z:=GF(2);}
\\\mathtt{P<x,y,z>:=PolynomialRing(Z,3);}$

But what I'd like is the structure to be such that, for example, $x^2 + y = 0$ and $yz + 1 = 0$ so that when I do calculations, whenever MAGMA "sees" $x^2 + y$ it just replaces it with $0$. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the help and apologies in advance if any of my formatting or asking etiquette is wrong; this is my first time asking on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `quo`-function, like this:

```
Q<x0,y0,z0> := quo<P | x^2+y, y*z+1>;
```

This gives you a new ring $Q$, which is isomorphic to $P$ modulo the ideal generated by $x^2+y$ and $yz+1$.

This is documented in the subsection "[Affine Algebras](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/affine_algebras)" of the section "Commutative Algebra" in the MAGMA handbook.

**Changing the normal form:** I think (but have not verified) that MAGMA always prints the element in normal form with respect to a Gröbner basis of the given ideal of relation. By changing the monomial order used to compute this basis, using `ChangeOrder`, you can change the normal form. This may allow you to specify a presentation of the elements that is preferable to you. (From your comment I infer that you may want to minimize total degree.) Witness the following Magma session:

```
> P<x,y,z>:=PolynomialRing(Z,3);
> P;
Polynomial ring of rank 3 over GF(2)
Order: Lexicographical
Variables: x, y, z
> Q<x0,y0,z0> := quo< P | x^2-y^3>;
> Q;                               
Affine Algebra of rank 3 over GF(2)
Lexicographical Order
Variables: x0, y0, z0
Quotient relations:
[
    x0^2 + y0^3
]
> x0^2;
y0^3
> y0^3;
y0^3
```

Here lexicographical order with $x>y$ is used, so the $x$-term is reduced to a $y$-term, even though the latter has larger degree.

Now we use a different order, specifying that monomials are first ordered by total degree, then by lexicographical order, so that $x^2 < y^3$.

```
> P:=ChangeOrder(P,"glex");        
> P;
Ideal of Polynomial ring of rank 3 over GF(2)
Order: Graded Lexicographical
Variables: x, y, z
Homogeneous
Basis:
[
    1
]

> Q<x0,y0,z0> := quo< P | x^2-y^3>;
> Q;
Ideal of Affine Algebra of rank 3 over GF(2)
Graded Lexicographical Order
Variables: x0, y0, z0
Quotient relations:
[
    y0^3 + x0^2
]
Generating basis:
[
    1
]
> x0^2;
x^2
> y0^3;
x^2
```

See the section on [Gröbner bases](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/groebner_bases) in the MAGMA handbook for more details and a list of possible orders.

Comment: This answers the question, thanks for the help. However, using this I encounter another issue. See, what I'm actually doing is in the field $GF(2)$ and the polynomial ring requires ten variables $x_1 ,\ldots, x_{10}$. What I wanted was to use relations like those above to simplify my calculations, however, when I have a relation like this: $x_1 + x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5$, MAGMA replaces every occurrence of $x_1$ with $x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5$. This makes sense from MAGMA's point of view as it's eliminating a variable, but what it does makes everything messy where using $x_1$ is simpler. Any advice here?

Comment: Maybe choosing a different monomial order on the polynomial ring is what you want. I don't know much about that, but see my comment for an example.